# Cordova iOS app crashes on multiple upload of files(Reactjs and redux)

Tags: ios, reactjs, cordova, redux, memory-leaks

**IOS app** crashes when *uploading multiple file*(especially those captured in **iOS camera**).

i created the **Cordova project** using

- Reactjs and Redux
- Axios for server calls

the **App** *crashes* when there is too much to sent to **server side**.for eg: App crashed when *i upload more than 10 photos* at time, but wont have any issue when *uploading less than 8 photos*.

in **Xcode** its showing there is a **memory** pressure and app gets *crashed*.

So i don't know how to debug this, tried to cut down memory leak by reducing the loops.

but still no hope

### has anyone had the same issue or do you guys know how to solve it?

i tried to reduce the memory pressure by cutting down loops.
but still app crashes when *uploading more than 10 photos at a time*

Comment: do you have any log of the crash ?

Answer (score 0):

When i usually implement an application for mobile apps , 
i consider that people are having different mobiles features , it could be high specification or low specifications depend on which mobile you are using , so
my suggestion to you is to make it conditional and do not allow users to select more than 8 files ( since it's working for you ) , and avoid allowing the user to select more because it might be the buffer / ram or it could be network issue / bandwidth issue or internet usage  or probably there isn't Enagph ram to process the uploaded photos or it could be internet / network issues / bandwidth / permission issues / libraries issues.

beside that , no one can tell you the exact problem here , you should use any bug tool to find the cause of the issue , i usually [use this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-debug)  to debug network requests / response

[here is a tested code](https://gist.github.com/BilalBudhani/97c36307bfb184d32f4125bcedc0fd55) that works for uploading multiple / photos i hope it can guide to catch the problem .